# Analysing seasonal variations in time series?

Tags: time-series, seasonality

I have to analyze `NDVI` time series over `17 years`. `NDVI` is `Normalized Difference Vegetation Index`, which represents the greenness in a pixel of satellite image and generally between -1 (non vegetation) to 1(maximum vegetation). I am going to use `MODIS NDVI` data at `16 days interval`.

I am specially interested in the seasonal variations of the time series. I want to see the variations or changes in the periodic components i.e frequency, amplitude and phase shift. How can I  extract these from time-series? Please suggest me where to start.

NDVI is Normalized Difference Vegetation Index, which represents the greenness in a pixel of satellite image and generally between -1 (non vegetation) to 1(maximum vegetation). I am going to use MODIS NDVI data at 16 days interval.

Comment: Can you pls explain NDVI?

Comment: NDVI is Normalized Difference Vegetation Index, which represents the greenness in a pixel of satellite image and generally between -1 (non vegetation) to 1(maximum vegetation). I am going to use MODIS NDVI data at 16 days interval.

Comment: Can you please add that extra information as an edit to the question? Not everybody reads comments ...

Comment: I suppose then you have many (very many?) parallel time series (for neighboring pixels.) In that case this is a spatio-temporal problem, as correlations with neighboring pixels should be of interest. Consider add the tag [tag:spatio-temporal]